# impossible to reach the "angular 4" option when "create new solution" in wakanda 2 on mac OS

Tags: angular, wakanda

I just installed "wakanda v 2" on my macbook...I try then the main tuto
https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/tutorial?section=main...I don't receive "angular 4" in the different propositions when I "create a new solution"...I just can reach "angular" or "angular 1"...It's thus impossible for me to follow the rest of this tutorial.

[image: screen copy of what happens]

Comment: Angular 2/4 has been called just Angular for a few months now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the angular team [announced earlier](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html), "**Angular 4**" will be referred as "**Angular**" version 4.0.0. So you will see "Angular" instead "Angular 4" or "Angular 2" in documentations and products that use Angular.

The Angular in Wakanda Studio drop-down shown in your screenshot is indeed referring to Angular 4.

You can find the version number of your Angular framework in the app root of any built angular page: [image: DOM]